# Aerospike In-Memory configuration

Tags: in-memory-database, aerospike

Consider a scenario in Aerospike:

*data-in-memory is set as true and memory space < disk space*

what happens when memory is filled up (stop-writes-pct is reached). Does aerospike stop accepting writes all together? OR it will continue to write to disk (if disk space is available) ?

How does the above behaviour is affected, in a multinode setup ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writes will start to fail completely when stop-writes-pct is reached. In data-in-memory configuration, stop-writes triggered by any reason (either disk or memory being full) will be honored by both.

This behavior is per node (since stop-writes-pct is related to a node and not to a cluster).

In case of a cluster, if its the node with the master copy of the data/partition which has hit stop-writes, that write will fail.

In case the node which has hit stop writes is supposed to be the replica partition node, the write is allowed for the replica data.

Answer (score 0):

**Single Node**

1. If *stop-writes-pct* is reached in memory, it will fail the write.
2. If *stop-writes-pct* is reached in the disk, it will fail the write.

**Aerospike Cluster**

1. If *stop-writes-pct* is reached in Master, it will fail the write.
2. If *stop-writes-pct* is reached in Replica, it will also fail due to *write.commit_level* being *all* by default.